# How to link Qt Designer button to a function in a separate file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new to Python and I've searched for an answer but couldn't find it (or rather couldn't properly implement it).

I've generated a window with a few buttons in QtDesigner's file named "arch.ui", converted to arch.py.

As I'll be updating GUI occasionally, I don't want to create functions in arch.py, so I've created a main.py file for that.

I've a problem with linking button click to a function => I try to link "btnSource" (from arch.py) to  function "printMe" (in main.py).

Obviously it doesn't work. Any help welcome.

Here is generated Designer file:

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'arch.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(460, 233)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnSource = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnSource.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 75, 23))
        self.btnSource.setObjectName("btnSource")
        self.lblSource = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblSource.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 60, 511, 21))
        self.lblSource.setObjectName("lblSource")
        self.lblTarget = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblTarget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 481, 16))
        self.lblTarget.setObjectName("lblTarget")
        self.btnTarget = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnTarget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 75, 23))
        self.btnTarget.setObjectName("btnTarget")
        self.btnGo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnGo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 120, 75, 23))
        self.btnGo.setObjectName("btnGo")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 460, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnSource.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Source"))
        self.lblSource.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.lblTarget.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.btnTarget.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Target"))
        self.btnGo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go"))
```

And here is my main.py file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from arch import Ui_MainWindow
import sys 

  
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
class myWindow(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__()
        self.btnSource.clicked.connect(self.btnSource.printMe)#

    def printMe(self):
        print('blah blah blah')

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Subclass from both `QMainWindow` *and* `Ui_MainWindow`, and call `setupUi` from there; then create an instance of `myWindow`:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnSource.clicked.connect(self.printMe)

    def printMe(self):
        print('blah blah blah')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MyWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Explanation

Your code doesn't work for many reasons; while the main problem might be that you actually *never* created an instance of `myWindow` (about that, you should always use capitalized names for classes), making it completely useless, it wouldn't have worked anyway.

That's because you should *not* subclass from the `ui` class object, but from the QWidget descendant (QMainWindow, in your case) you're going to use.

The `ui_*` objects created from `pyuic` are only intended as a high level (and **unmodified**) interface to create the UI *on top* of a QWidget subclass.
Calling `setupUi(something)` actually creates all child widgets for the widget `something`, sets the layout and, possibly, [automatically connects to slots with a compatible name](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name), but that's all: in fact, if you closely look at the code from the ui file, it actually does nothing besides `setupUi` and `retranslateUi` (nor it should!): there's not even an `__init__`!

If you need to add interaction and create connections from signals to slot/functions, you should use the single/multiple inheritance approaches as explained in the official guide about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) with PyQt; the only other possibility is to use `loadUi` (while still subclassing from the base class) with the source `.ui` file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('path/to/gui.ui', self)
        self.someWidget.someSignal.connect(self.someSlot)
        # ...

    def someSlot(self, signalArguments, [...]):
        # do something...
```

<sub>PS: for various reasons, it's usually better to run a QApplication only if the script is the one that's been run (hence the `if __name__ ...`), mostly because there should be just only *one* QApplication instance for every running program; in any case, it shouldn't be created *before* the class declarations (unless, you **really** know what you're doing); it's not a big deal in your case, but, as usual, better safe than sorry.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for very informative response and explanation. Unfortunately the solution doesn't work -> AttributeError: 'QPushButton' object has no attribute 'printMe'

Comment: Sorry, I just copied from your code (which was wrong to begin with): it should point to `self.printMe`, since the function is a member of the class instance (`self`).

Comment: That works!. Thank you very much!